# How do you create Collections in Brightspot CMS using Java classes with the Dari framework?

Tags: java, content-management-system

```
import com.psddev.cms.db.Content;
import com.psddev.dari.db.Recordable;

public class MattContent extends Content { 
    private String tt;
    private String uu;

    public String getUu() {
        return uu;
    }

    public MattContent setUu(String uu) {
        this.uu = uu;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTt() {
        return tt;
    }

    public MattContent setTt(String tt) {
        this.tt = tt;
        return this;
    }

    @Recordable.DisplayName("Headline")
    private String title;

    @Recordable.DisplayName("Fields")
    private String fields;

    @Recordable.Regex(value=".+\\@.+\\..+", validationMessage="Use email format 'myemail@address.com'")
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The code above renders individual fields in the UI from a Java class using the Dari framework in Brightspot CMS. I would like to do more than individual fields, but Collections as well.

I can see how to set up a Collection for users in the docs:

https://docs.brightspot.com/4.0/en/plugins-guide/collections/creating-collections.html

However, I cannot find the annotation in Dari to set this up for devs:

https://docs.brightspot.com/4.2/en/dari-guide/data-modeling/data-modeling-annotations.html

I'd really appreciate any help in pointing me to the right section of the documentation. This may be a vocabulary issue -- I may not be typing in the right words to get this information.

*"Cluster" isn't yielding the results I'm looking for either.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: There is no annotation needed for a collection. One can write a simple set or list:

```
 private Set<Internal> internalSet;
 private List<Internal> internalList;
```

The solution is so simple, I overlooked the obvious: annotations are extras in Dari, not essential for rendering content to Brightspot CMS' UI.